# Photography pros: can anyone help me find out which lens is on this camera?

Tags: lens, canon, depth-of-field, wide-aperture

[http://i.imgur.com/fGLh4Pb.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/fGLh4Pb.jpg)

And it takes photos like this? [http://i.imgur.com/BK5vPRw.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/BK5vPRw.jpg)
I'm desperately trying to find which lens will allow me to take photos like this. I already have a canon camera.

Comment: Lens aside, *do not take photos like this*. Putting a child on a train trestle is incredibly irresponsible. What would you do if a train came? Tell her to jump?

Comment: @mattdm If he doesn't know what the lens is, he obviously doesn't have it and didn't take the picture? Or are you assuming he meant on train tracks, rather than the crappy bokeh? lol

Comment: what makes you IMMEDIATELY jump to an uninformed assumption that the track was in regular use Matt?????

Comment: @Digital Lightcraft Guessing that they aren't, or that it will be easy to tell if a train is coming, is how people end up dead. And obviously Kristy didn't take *this* picture — the warning is against imitating it. And that said, the tracks and bridge look recently maintained. Why on earth would you IMMEDIATELY jump to the defense of such reckless behavior? Here's a story from less than a month ago: http://petapixel.com/2015/09/18/teen-struck-and-killed-on-train-tracks-during-photo-shoot-with-girlfriend/

Comment: Can we keep the comments on topic? I.e. asking clarifying information about the question to better answer it or to suggest improvements.

Comment: The question contains an image link that is of a dangerous and illegal activity. It would be irresponsible for anyone who knows better to endorse such behavior by remaining silent.

Comment: All those comments aside, this question needs a title which actually describes the lens to be identified.

Comment: Since both links to images in the OP are dead, I'm voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

The lens in the camera in the picture you linked appears to be either the EF 50mm f/1.8  or the EF 50mm f/1.8 II. The latter can still be purchased but there is a newer version, the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM, that was recently released that is available for about the same price new.

Here is an [excellent review](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-50mm-f-1.8-STM-Lens.aspx) of the newest version that compares the two.

Please don't take pictures like your example, though! Not only is it trespassing to be on railroad property but it is very dangerous. Trespassing on a bridge or trestle is particularly hazardous because there is no quick escape route if a train approaches. **There are between three and four hundred deaths per year in the united States due to people being where they shouldn't on railroad property and being struck by trains.** Trains can't stop very easily and usually by the time they see a person on the tracks it is too late for them to stop until they are well past the point where the person was spotted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the canon 50mm f/1.8, to me...